# Cass variable initialization in __init__ in one line

Tags: python, constructor, self

I was wondering if there is an elegant way to initialize multiple class variables in one line. Consider the following class:

```
class Myclass():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f):
        self.a = b
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        self.e = e
        self.f = f
```

I know i could do the following but with longer variable names this format **loses readability**.

```
class Myclass():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f):
        self.a, self.b, self.c, self.d, self.e, self.f = a, b, c, d, e, f
```

Is there a different way to create class variables with the corresponding name for all arguments to in one line?

Comment: This should not have been closed. The other question was in 2009. The best way to do this now is (often) with dataclasses, which are python 3.7

Comment: @Neil the other question has an answer using dataclasses.

Comment: Ah I see ohkay.